# Как из консольного приложения c# выполнить команду dism?

Tags: c#, powershell

Команда 1 выполняется в powershell

```
Dism /online /Get-FeatureInfo /FeatureName:TFTP
```

В приложении c# ничего не выполняется, открывается консоль и больше ничего не происходит:

```
ProcStartargs("powershell",
            "-command \" Dism /online /Get-FeatureInfo /FeatureName:TFTP \"");

public static void ProcStartargs(string name, string args)
        {
            try
            {
                var proc = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = name,
                        Arguments = args,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866)
                    }
                };
                proc.Start();
                // ReSharper disable once NotAccessedVariable
                string line = null;
                while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line += Environment.NewLine + proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                }
                proc.WaitForExit();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Команда 2 тоже не работает

```
ProcStartargs("powershell", 
        "-command \" Dism /Mount-Image/ ImageFile:d:\\_images\\install.wim /Index:1 /mountdir:d:\\_images\\_test \"");
```

Answer (score 2):

[dism.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh825265.aspx) - это отдельная программа, а не команда powershell. Зачем запускать ее через powershell-то?

Comment: Так тоже не работает
`ProcStartargs(@"Dism.exe", @"/Mount-Image/ ImageFile:d:\_images\install.wim /Index:1 /mountdir:z:\_images\_test2");`
   
`ProcStartargs(@"Dism.exe", @"/online /Get-FeatureInfo /FeatureName:TFTP");`

Comment: @codename0082016 что значит "не работает"?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process MyProc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
   MyProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-d..ervicing-management_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_2fff730f6c019e77\Dism.exe";
   MyProc.StartInfo.Verb = "/Get-Help";
   MyProc.Start();`
Необработанное исключение типа "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception" в System.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Указанному файлу не сопоставлено ни одно приложение для выполнения данной операции

Comment: @codename0082016 откуда у вас взялся verb?

Comment: опечатка там Arguments. Теперь ошибка Ошибка 87: Параметр задан неверно.

`System.Diagnostics.Process MyProc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
   MyProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-d..ervicing-management_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_2fff730f6c019e77\Dism.exe";
   MyProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/Get-Help";
   MyProc.Start();`

Comment: @codename0082016 вам уже ответили в вашем [предыдущем вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562245/106). Зачем плодить копии?

Comment: не предыдущий а следующий

Answer (score 0):

```
Process MyProc = new Process();
            MyProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"Dism.exe";
            MyProc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/Mount-Image /ImageFile:d:\_images\install.wim /Index:1 /mountdir:d:\_images\_test2";
            MyProc.Start();
```