# Консольное приложение не может передать параметр Dism

Tags: c#

```
var a = @"Dism.exe";
var aa = @"/Mount-Image/ ImageFile:z:\_images\install.wim /Index:1 /mountdir:z:\_images\_test2";
Process.Start(a, aa);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info                  DISM   PID=2880 TID=5308 
>   Scratch directory set to 'C:\Users\z\AppData\Local\Temp\'. -
>   CDISMManager::put_ScratchDir 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   PID=2880 TID=5308 DismCore.dll version: 10.0.14393.0 -
>   CDISMManager::FinalConstruct 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   Try to initialize Panther logging 1 times, last error: 0x0
>   2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info                  DISM   PID=2880 TID=5308
>   Successfully loaded the ImageSession at "C:\Windows\System32\Dism" -
>   CDISMManager::LoadLocalImageSession 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   Try to initialize Panther logging 1 times, last error: 0x0
>   2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store:
>   PID=2880 TID=5308 Found and Initialized the DISM Logger. -
>   CDISMProviderStore::Internal_InitializeLogger 2016-09-02 22:29:03,
>   Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2880 TID=5308
>   Failed to get and initialize the PE Provider.  Continuing by assuming
>   that it is not a WinPE image. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
>   2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store:
>   PID=2880 TID=5308 Finished initializing the Provider Map. -
>   CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2880 TID=5308 Getting Provider
>   DISMLogger - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2880 TID=5308 Provider has previously
>   been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. -
>   CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   Try to initialize Panther logging 1 times, last error: 0x0
>   2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store:
>   PID=2880 TID=5308 Getting Provider DISMLogger -
>   CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2880 TID=5308 Provider has previously
>   been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. -
>   CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   DISM Manager: PID=2880 TID=5308 Successfully created the local
>   image session and provider store. -
>   CDISMManager::CreateLocalImageSession 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2880 TID=5308 Getting Provider
>   DISMLogger - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2880 TID=5308 Provider has previously
>   been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. -
>   CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   DISM.EXE:  2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info                  DISM
>   DISM.EXE: <----- Starting Dism.exe session -----> 2016-09-02 22:29:03,
>   Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE:  2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   DISM.EXE: Host machine information: OS Version=10.0.14393,
>   Running architecture=x86, Number of processors=1 2016-09-02 22:29:03,
>   Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: Failed validating command line:
>   "C:\Windows\System32\Dism.exe" /Mount-Image/
>   ImageFile:z:_images\install.wim /Index:1 /mountdir:z:_images_test2
>   2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image
>   session has been closed. Reboot required=no. 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   DISM.EXE:  2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info                  DISM
>   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session -----> 2016-09-02 22:29:03,
>   Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE:  2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2880 TID=5308 Found the OSServices. 
>   Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. -
>   CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect 2016-09-02 22:29:03, Info
>   DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2880 TID=5308 Releasing the local
>   reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. -
>   CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider

Answer (score 3):

Похоже что пробел стоит не в том месте. Вместо `/Mount-Image/ ImageFile` должно быть `/Mount-Image /ImageFile`.